# Firebase - Firestore Collection Group indexes in free tier

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Are Collection Group Queries not available in the Firebase free tier?  When I try and create one the spinner never completes and the status is pending.

Comment: From what I know firestore queries do not differ between free and paid tiers. Would you mind providing a little more detail about your code. A code snippet of the query you are firing might help identify the problem. 
Also consider this blog which talks about collection group indexes https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

Comment: Thanks - your comment made me look at my code more closely and I now have an enabled index!

Comment: The ability to create indexes is the same between the free tier and the paid tier of Firestore. Most likely you just need to be more patient, as the initial creation of an index can take quite some time.

Comment: @Townheadbluesboy Would you mind pointing out what change had to made in your code. It might help someone else who stumbles upon the same problem,

Comment: Sure Less code more a mixture of stupidity and confusion!  -

- . For the 'create index from error' url in the console available when an index is needed make sure you're logged in to Chrome only once on your machine - I had 2 accounts logged in and I wanted to create the index in the 2nd one (i.e. not the default).

-  When you build an index in the GUI make sure you have the correct Collection selected.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, according to the doc the [`free quota`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) includes:

- `Stored data` 1 GiB.
- `Document reads`  50,000 per day.
- `Document writes` 20,000 per day.
- `Document deletes`    20,000 per day.
- `Network egress`  10 GiB per month.

As the OP said, be careful when you're logged into multiple accounts on google an make sure to be in the right one in order to use the Firestore services.